# Preciso clonar o conteudo de uma div e colocar no form de meu modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-3

Boa tarde pessoal.

Mais uma vez recorro a vocês sobre um problema que tenho.
Estou precisando usar a sintaxe abaixo em um modal.

```
$("#divConsulta").clone().appendTo($("#formFruta"));
```

Na linha abaixo ao clicar, eu abro meu modal com o formulário de dados a atualizar:

```
<a href="<c:url value="edita?cod=${fruta.cod}"/>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update-modal" title="Editar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
```

O prolema é que não sei como fazer esse:

> clone().appendTo

para o meu modal.

Resumindo, não sei se estou correta, preciso passar o conteudo de uma div que está em uma página, que ao ser clicado o botão de abrir modal, o conteudo de #divConsulta vá para o #formFruta que esta em um modal do Bootstrap.

Espero ter sido clara, pois estou a horas tentando isso.

Grata

Comment: Eu acredito que não precisa usar o $('#formFruta') para identificar o elemento, usa apenas ('#formFruta'). Ficaria assim: $("#divConsulta").clone().appendTo("#formFruta");

Comment: @Ricardo lendo a documentação (http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) o método `appendTo` aceita como parâmetro: selector, element, HTML string, array de elementos ou objeto jQuery, portanto o `$('#formFruta')` é um valor válido. O problema deve ser outro.

Comment: O elemento com o ID `formFruta` existe no momento que o append é executado? Ocorre algum erro? Dê uma olhada na console do browser para ver se alguma exception é disparada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema pode ser que quando você tenta inserir o conteúdo clonado do elemento `#divConsulta`, o conteúdo do modal ainda não foi inserido no [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) e, portanto, o elemento `#formFruta` ainda não está disponível para manipulação com Javascript.

Tente os [eventos](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#events) `shown.bs.modal` ou `show.bs.modal` do Boostrap:

```
$("#update-modal").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#divConsulta").clone().appendTo($("#formFruta"));
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim: $("#divConsulta").clone().appendTo("#formFruta");

Dá uma olhada nesse teste que eu fiz, vê se te ajuda: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XdZyioV364cZPP9M67nA)

Comment: Lendo a documentação (api.jquery.com/appendto) o método appendTo aceita como parâmetro: selector, element, HTML string, array de elementos ou objeto jQuery, portanto o $('#formFruta') é um valor válido.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a melhor formar de se fazer isso é com o append e não o appendTo.
Você pode usar assim:

```
var div = $("#divConsulta").clone();
$("#formFruta").append(div);
```

Dessa forma você está adicionando um conteúdo clonado ao formulário.